# Enable multi instance of neo4j on same server , but http port is disaballed and https port enabled with different port number for two instances

Tags: neo4j

Is possible to enable multi instance of neo4j enterprise edition  on same server  , but the http port is disabled on both instances  and two instance with different configurations having two different port numbers  for https , if so please let me know the process

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the zip installation, not any of the package installations ... and make as many copies of the installation directory as you need instances
2. Modify **neo4j.conf** in each instance directory and make sure the following parameters are different in each :

   dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:**XXXX**

   dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:**YYYY**

   dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:**ZZZZ**

Also make sure that you explicitely assign memory to each instance (or they'll fight for it).

Start each instance from it's instance directory and you should have no conflicts.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: but i have disabled  # dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:YYYY  for security reasons in the organisation  and only using https port to access the neo4j , both instances  have different bolt and https   ports and no other service is running on the ports  , at a time i am able to bring up one instance ,  is there way to bring up both instances

Comment: You should be able to bring up both of them ... what errors are you getting ?

Comment: FAILED ServerConnector@669b1c83{HTTP/1.1}{xxx.0.0.1:7474}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)

Comment: Can you still set specific (different) ports for dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:YYYY please ? even with dbms.connector.http.enabled=false (I assume you've got that too ?) and even if http is not exposed to the outside, Neo4j might use it itself.

Comment: instance 1 (  up and running )
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
#dbms.connector.http.enabled=false
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7474
# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7473

Comment: instance 2 (could not bring up service )
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7688

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
#dbms.connector.http.enabled=false
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7476

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7478

Comment: # HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7474
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=127.0.0.1:7474

Comment: thanks for your support and your idea to use different port for two instances helped

Comment: # HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7476
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=127.0.0.1:7476